# Kotlinx serialization parsing enum ignore unknown value

Tags: json, kotlinx.serialization

I've a json which looks like:

```
[
  {
    "object": [
      {
        "enumValue1": "value1",
        "value2": 1
       }
    ],
  },
  {
    "object2": [
      {
        "enumValue1": "value2",
        "value2": 2
       }
    ],
  },
  {
    "object3": [
      {
        "enumValue1": "value1",
        "value2": 3
       }
    ],
  },
  {
    "object4": [
      {
        "enumValue1": "unknown",
        "value2": 4
       }
    ],
  },
]
```

I want to parse this json with kotlinx serialization
I've created a class and an enum:

```
@Serializable
data class Class {
  @SerialName("enumValue1")
  val enumValue1: EnumValue

  @SerialName("value2")
  val value2: Int
}

@Serializable
enum class EnumValue {
  @SerialName("value1") VALUE_1,
  @SerialName("value2") VALUE_2
}
```

I expect the output of the parsing to be a list, with 3 objects in (object with value "unknown" not parsed)

How could I achieve it?
I have try:

```
ignoreUnknownKeys = true
coerceInputValues = true
```

But it doesn' work:

```
Field 'enumValue1' is required for type with serial name, but it was missing
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You may need to declare enumValue1 as nullable, like this:

Comment: (1) You don't show the code where serialization happens. What are you trying to serialize? (It should be `List<Class>`) (2) Which instances do you expect to get in your list? Clearly they cannot be instances of `Class`, since it contains `EnumValue` which can't be "unknown". This hints at a different question/solution than what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare enumValue1 as nullable:

```
val enumValue1: EnumValue?
```

That will make it optional.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, if I do that, the output will have 4 objects right? I only want 3 objects, without any filtering after the parsing

Comment: Hi - Sorry I didn't get it at first - I don't know how you can do that :-(.

Comment: @RaviWallau can you please take a look on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73064940/11560810)